# How to find who downloaded data from Google Cloud Platform: Services:“Cloud Storage“, SKUs „Download Worldwide Destinations“

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-logging

Is it possible to find the IP address or the e-mail address of a Google Cloud Platform user who has downloaded a large amount of data from Cloud Storage over a past period of time?

Can anyone explain how to do it using gcloud command-line tool?

Comment: You need Storage Usage Logs enabled which is disabled by default. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#should-you-use

Comment: @Simon -  Did you get this working? I keep seeing Monitoring as a better solution to this but I don't see where the IP info is.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable Storage Usage Logs (they are disabled by default as John Hanley mentioned), here's what the documentation has to say about it:

> Storage logs provide information about the storage consumption of that bucket for the last day and are created daily. Once set up, usage logs and storage logs are automatically created as new objects in a bucket that you specify.

To check the status of the logs you can use `gsutil` command:

```
gsutil logging get gs://example-bucket
```

If logging is enabled, the server returns the logging configuration in the response:

```
{"logBucket": "example-logs-bucket", "logObjectPrefix": "log_object_prefix"}
```

You will then be able to see the IP address that made the request but no email.

Have a look at the [log format](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#format) to see what other values they contain:

`c_ip`- The IP address from which the request was made. The "c" prefix indicates that this is information about the client.